# Controller is geting an empty object when receiving ajax post request from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, post, reactjs

I'm creating a react javascript component which gathers information from the user and sends a post request to an url endpoint using ajax. My component is reaching the endpoint. Here's the codes exemplifying my problem:

C# endpoint - Controller:

```
[EnhancedRequireHttps]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyMethod(MyObject myObject)
    {...}
```

The object which I'm expecting:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name;
    public string Number;
    public long Id;
    public int Code;
}
```

javascript data:

```
this.props.newValues = {
    Name : "John",
    Number : "1234567890",
    Id : "1234",
    Code : 1
}
```

javascript ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: this.props.endpointurl, // Contains the endpoint
        data: this.props.newValues,

        success: function(response) {
        }.bind(this),

        error: function(err) {
        }.bind(this)
    });
```

Previously, I had all the parameters as my MyMethod's input, like this:

```
[EnhancedRequireHttps]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyMethod(string Name, string Number, long Id, int Code)
    {...}
```

and the post was working properly, but I'm trying to make a clean code, so I created a class to contain those attributes, and when I did so, my problem started.

I tried creating an object named myObject to contain my parameters in the js code. 
I also tried using $(this.props.newValues).serialize() or JSON.stringify(this.props.newValues), and dataType = "json" or contentType = "application/json".

Thanks for reading and helping, I'm here to clear any doubt regarding my situation. :)

Comment: Calling JSON.stringify(this.props.newValues) in console produces correct JSON, e.g. like this: "{"Name":"John","Number":"1234567890","Id":"1234","Code":1}"

Comment: I tried using this method, knowing that the default binder would treat the JSON income, but my request came out empty on the controller

Comment: What do you see in the network tools of your favourite browser? Can you see the payload being sent? If so, try manually sending a payload with postman to see if the problem is server-side: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: @DavidGilbertson The payload is being sent:
`Name: John
Number:1234567890
Id:1234
Code:1`
But the controller is receiving an empty object. Using postman the same thing is occurring

Comment: Well, just to clearify, the object is empty:
The long and int types are receiving 0 (default value) and the strings null (again, default value)

Comment: OK so if the issue is the same with postman we've ruled out javascript and react, and that's all I know I'm afraid :). I assume you're sending over https if `EnhancedRequireHttps` means what I guess it would mean.

Comment: Yeah, concluded the same... I think I'll be posting the answer soon, I have a much more experienced coworker who might know how to solve this problem, I'll tag you if you want. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify contentType and send json as a string. See comments:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // Try to add this
    url: this.props.endpointurl,
    data: JSON.stringify(this.props.newValues), // And this

    success: function(response) {
    }.bind(this),

    error: function(err) {
    }.bind(this)
});
```

Comment: I added some edit information to my doubt, but I'm trying out your code right now, didn't use "charset = utf-8"

Comment: Well, thats awkward, but I'm not sure if your solution would work or not because I'm having CORS problems using your setup. Any clue why? I tried adding:
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value =(componentHost) /> to my endpoint application config and I also added xhrFields : {withCredentials: true} to my ajax call.

Comment: Sorry, no clue about CORS.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway, I think there's one little syntax tweak I need to do that will clear everything. As I said, I had it working before the MyObject class.

Comment: You don't need to set contentType if you use `$.post()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/. It will correct stringify JSON for you if you pass an object to `data`.

Comment: The same goes if I specify the type o request inside, Using type: "POST"? Just asking out of curiosity.